# Not triggering keypress on WebForms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

Im maintaining a webforms application.

there is an `.ascx` where I have the following script on top of the `.ascx` after the registers:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=txtMotivoRechazo.ClientID%>').keypress(function () {
                var cantCaracteres = this.val().length;

                if (cantCaracteres >= 250) {
                    $('#<%=lblCuentaCaracteres.ClientID%>').css('color', 'red');
                }
                else {
                    $('#<%=lblCuentaCaracteres.ClientID%>').css('color', 'black');
                }

                $('#<%=lblCuentaCaracteres.ClientID%>').text(cantCaracteres);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `asp:label lblCuentaCaracteres` and the `asp:textbox txtMotivoRechazo` are inside an `UpdatePanel` and inside a `ContentTemplate`

Simplified, this is the ascx:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=txtMotivoRechazo.ClientID%>').keypress(function () {
                    var cantCaracteres = this.val().length;

                    if (cantCaracteres >= 250) {
                        $('#<%=lblCuentaCaracteres.ClientID%>').css('color', 'red');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#<%=lblCuentaCaracteres.ClientID%>').css('color', 'black');
                    }

                    $('#<%=lblCuentaCaracteres.ClientID%>').text(cantCaracteres);
            });
        });
    </script>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMensaje" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlMotivoRechazo" runat="server" Height="100%" ScrollBars="Auto" TabIndex="-1" class="tcFilterContent">
                    <div id="MotivoRechazo" >
                        <h2>Motivo del Rechazo</h2>
                        <div id="MensajeEmail">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMensajeNoSupera" runat="server" CssClass="MensajeCaracteres"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCuentaCaracteres" runat="server" CssClass="CuentaCaracteres"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMensajeCuentaCaracteres" runat="server" CssClass="CuentaCaracteres"></asp:Label>

                        </div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMotivoRechazo" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Width="100%" MaxLength="250" CssClass="txt3c3"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tcButtonList" id="divBotonesRechazo">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRechazarPreAceptar" runat="server" Text="Aceptar" OnClick="btnRechazarPreAceptar_Click" class="button"/>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But when I write something inside the textbox is not triggering the keypress, I tried the same with keydown or keyup. 
I tried using:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="txtMotivoRechazo" />
</Triggers>
```

In case is related to the update panel, Im not that familiarized with webforms.

Comment: change the  `$(document).ready(function () {})` with `pageLoad(){ ... } ` and see if its works. This is because of Update panel. If works i will explain on the answer. The function is case sensitive

Comment: "Error in time of execution of javascript, the object does not accept the property or method val"

Comment: Which is weird because they have their jQuery loaded on the master page

Comment: Ok, is $(this).val(). Please make this an answer and explain so I can upvote it. Is working.

Comment: then the issue is on `this` - there find again your control with jQuery